# Key to mute my Skype mic?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, skype, microphone, mute

I'm using a Mac.
Is there a keyboard shortcut for muting the mic during a call?
I can't find one, and I often need to toggle mute/unmute.
Clicking the button on the Skype interface is very inconvenient :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use spacebar to toggle mute/unmute.

Credit: http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=70965&view=findpost&p=2216171

Comment: The Skype window has to be the one in focus to do this, but it works well.

Comment: Doesn't work at all for me.

Comment: Fairly sure this is out of date, try Shift-Cmd-M as per my other answer.

Answer (score 16):

When Skype is focused, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> toggles the microphone.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>­­ ↑</kbd> also mutes the microphone for me, and works globally. 
However, it's not a toggle; as noted below, it switches to Push To Talk mode, in which the mic is muted by default but will be unmuted as long as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>­­ ↑</kbd> is pressed.

I'm on OS X 10.8, with the latest version of Skype as of 10/16/2012.

Comment: Note that the mentioned keyboard shortcut:
`Ctrl Alt Command ↑`
also functions as Push To Talk (PTT) when the microphone is muted.

Comment: This should be the selected answer

Comment: Perfect, I'd been looking for this for a while - "Control + Option + Command + Up" is the winner! Works globally too, so you don't need to have Skype in focus.

Comment: I was using this and found this very useful. But since the update of Skype 8 on Mac, this shortcut has stopped working... The Cmd + Shift + M still works tho. Microsoft just made it so embarrassing.

Answer (score 12):

While the application does not have a built in keyboard shortcut for it you can add one using the Keyboard Shortcuts feature in the Keyboard Preference Pane in System Preferences.

1. Open System Preferences
2. Open Keyboard
3. Change to the Keyboard Shortcuts section (If using Snow Leopard click Application Shortcuts on the left side)
4. Press the '+' button.
5. Select Skype as the Application
6. Menu Title: "Mute"
7. Choose a Keyboard Shortcut (eg. Command-Option-M as Command-M is used for minimize.)
8. Press OK, close System Preferences and restart Skype if it was open.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using F15. Easy to find in the dark, and never used anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Shift-Cmd-M for me works in Skype 7.59 for Mac, which is the current version (and I really don't *remember* configuring it myself). You'll find Mute Microphone in the Conversations menu.

See also: [Skype's own list](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12025/what-are-hotkeys-and-how-do-i-use-them-in-skype).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a way to do this so you can mute yourself from anywhere in the Mac OS operating system, follow my how-to guide. This is extremely handy because you do not have to go to/from Skype or any other applications you're using for video conferencing.

https://medium.com/macoclock/how-in-the-bleep-do-i-mute-my-mic-anywhere-on-macos-d2fa1185b13

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: @DavidPostill: How do you suggest he does that, given the explanation being pretty long?

Comment: @Moreaki It's not that long if you leave out the images (which are not essential parts of the answer).

Comment: @DavidPostill: Fair enough, though I reckon it might be difficult to follow, and as soon as any interface of the mentioned tools changes, the information is probably useless.

Comment: Hey @ikaerom,Still works 2 years later because I’m not automating the interface.